# Write an integer number as binary to a file with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, binaryfiles

I'm trying to write an unsigned integer (its 4-byte DWORD binary representation) to a file with PowerShell, but all the alternatives I've tried only write text.

Let's say I have this number:

`$number = [Int] 255`

The file content should be `FF000000` (binary), not `255` (text).

I'm not a PowerShell expert, so I appreciate any help.

Comment: your question is ambiguous. signed/unsigned integer. How do you write/read the file. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
$number = [Int] 255
# Convert the number to a byte[4] array
$bytes  = [System.BitConverter]::GetBytes($number)
# Write the bytes to a file
Add-Content -Path "D:\FILE.BIN" -Value $bytes -Encoding Byte
```

Comment: That's neat, didn't know about the `Byte` encoding of `Add-Content`. Keep in mind that cmdlet appends to files, but I imagine `-Encoding Byte` will work with `Set-Content` and possibly `Out-File` as well.

Comment: Fast-forward to 2024 and `-Encoding Byte` is now `-AsByteStream`

Answer (score 3):

For this I think we need to rely on .Net classes.

You can get an array of bytes `[byte[]]` by using `[System.BitConverter]::GetBytes()`.

From there you need a way to write bytes to the file without them being converted to strings.

For that, use `[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes()`.

So combined, code like this would do it:

```
$number = [int]255
$bytes = [System.BitConverter]::GetBytes($number)
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes('C:\MyPath\To\File.bin', $bytes)
```

Comment: I've just posted an answer at the same time, doing almost the exact same thing.

Comment: @karliwson yup seems we were a few seconds apart!